I need to convert my Blazor SSR app to Blazor WebAssembly app
I Have created a new .Net Aspire Starter app which created a default Blazor Static server app for me. And now I need to convert it to Blazor WebAssembly without breaking the Aspire connection. How can we do that?
I have tried diffrent ways like creating a new WebAssembly app in that solution and migrated everything to it. But it didn't worked.

With no information on what's in your Static Server App, this question is impossible to answer.

@MrCakaShaunCurtis in my Server app I have these in my Program.cs which adds the service defaults & Aspire components. Now How can we add these in my new WebAssembly app?
Program.cs (SSR app)
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
// Add service defaults & Aspire components.
builder.WebHost.UseStaticWebAssets();
builder.AddServiceDefaults();

It doesn't help.  I think the only way to answer this is through either a [MRE] or Github repo.
